# Why does using a Poco Model for my embedded ViewComponent in an external assembly throw Assembly Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a Poco Model, in an external assembly where the actual view component is located.

```
 public class HeaderModel
{
    public HeaderModel()
    {
        MainMenuItems = new List<MainMenuItem>();
    }

    public string ViewComponentName { get; set; }
    public List<MainMenuItem> MainMenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

I'm then returning it as the model for the view component

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var headerModel = new HeaderModel
        {
            ViewComponentName = ApplicationConfiguration.Configuration.Settings.Ui.RightSidebar.ViewComponentName,
            MainMenuItems = MenuProvider.GetTopMenu().ToList()
        };


        return View(headerModel);
    }
```

When I do this I get a:

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'UiSmart.Module, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The funny thing is that if I specify an IEnumerable as my model type it works fine, but the moment I use a Poco model in the view it has a hissy fit, and even more annoying is that the model is defined in the same assembly as the view component .cs and .cshtml page.

I have a feeling that the view is running in the context of the server and the actual assembly it belongs to is no longer in context/referenced, but it is added as an application part during start-up.

So I'm very confused.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: could this uismart.module be referenced in that external assembly and necessary for that HeaderModel?

Comment: The idea is to have standalone modules, so if you would like a ui then you just copy the dll into the modules folder and voila you have a ui. so referencing that would kinda defeat the purpose, I don't want the server to care about the ui module, just serve what it exposes.

Comment: What is UiSmart.Module, and where are you referencing it? It might just not be copied to the output folder.

Comment: ok, but what happens if you reference that UiSmart.Module in your UI project - is the error gone then or is it still there, or do you get a different error? I'm just guessing that some stuff from that module might be leaking into your UI project

Comment: Ok so the problem is sorted, instead of copying the module dlls to a Modules folder after the build, I'm copying it now to the webbapps bin folder, and all is well, essentially saying that as long as the module is located side by side of the entry assembly all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem is sorted, instead of copying the module dlls to a Modules folder after the build, I'm copying it now to the webbapps bin folder, and all is well, essentially saying that as long as the modules are located side by side of the entry assembly it will work.